# Where to find US Cadastral data?

Tags: usa

Where to find US Cadastral data similar to Montana Cadastral Framework.
I would like to download taxable parcels and non-taxable parcels shape files.

http://geoinfo.msl.mt.gov/msdi/cadastral/
Service Description: The Montana Cadastral Framework provides a digital representation of the written legal description of taxable parcels and non-taxable parcels, or land ownership, as defined in the Montana Department of Revenue's (DOR) Computer Assisted Mass Appraisal database (CAMA) The non-taxable parcels may include public lands (federal, state, local governments, etc.), tribal lands in USA or tribal trust, and other exempt property such as church owned property. The boundaries of aliquot parcels are built on the Bureau of Land Management’s Geographic Coordinate Database (GCDB). The non-aliquot parcels (parcels based on bearings and distances) are/were created through the use of coordinate geometry (COGO) and/or original digitization of paper and Mylar maps or deeds and still primarily reside on a GIS base.

Comment: on the FTP site (Shapefile and Geodatabase) http://ftp.geoinfo.msl.mt.gov/Data/Spatial/MSDI/Cadastral/Parcels/

Comment: Might be better asked on [opendata.se] stack exchange

Comment: The US generally doesn't have a cadastre. Counties keep their own databases and it sounds like you want the tax assessor's data rather than deed or cadastral information. I think there are a few companies who have wider holdings but they're not free.

Comment: So it seems only Montana has this database?

Comment: water https://marinecadastre.gov/